# Which nerve inflammation can affect vision other than the optical nerve itself?

Tags: ophthalmology, nerves, optic-nerve

Which nerve inflammation can affect vision other than the optical nerve itself?
Can a nerve inflammation affect vision?

Comment: The oculomotor nerve (III), trochlear nerve (IV) and abducens nerve (VI), which innervate the eye muscles. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranial_nerves and the nerves that innervate the ciliary muscles (that control the lens) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciliary_muscle .

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: @Jan - That has enough information and references to make it a good answer.

Comment: Hi all, thank you Jan, that seems a good point to start from. Carey, I  did some research about the optical nerve and then about chinese meridians, I am looking for other nerves that can affect vision other than the cranial ones, from other parts of the body. I am sorry if I didn't respect the guidelines I am used to stack overflow where you are guided in the question form and I thought here there wasn't a strict structure.  The punishing -1 is not inviting, though. Also, how can I upvote Jan answer?

Comment: PS: I know chinese meridians are NOT nerves. I saw many pages about the nervous system and structure but I didn't find correlations able to provide info about my question. I also googled on google scholar eye impairment due to nerve inflammation or something similar.

Comment: Hi AMDP, welcome to MedSci. Things are different here than on StackOverflow, but not _that_ much different. For example, SO requires you to demonstrate an attempt to solve a problem before asking for a solution. We do exactly the same. Questions are expected to demonstrate some level of effort in the form of prior research. Those wikipedia articles Jan posted in his comment are a good example. Had those links been in your question, I wouldn't have commented and you probably wouldn't have a downvote (I wasn't the downvoter).

Comment: Just as lack of prior effort will get your question closed on SO, lack of prior research will get your question closed here too. You'll find that requirement on many exchanges, particularly science exchanges, so MedSci isn't unusual in that regard.

Comment: @CareyGregory, I'm him, not her.

Comment: @Jan My apologies. Edited to correct.

Answer (score 2):

The vision can be sharp when the light is focused exactly on the retina, not in front or behind it. This is enabled by the constant eye bulb length and the ability of the lens to accommodate to near or far objects.

**Three cranial nerves** that innervate the extraocular muscles and thus the shape of the eye bulb include the oculomotor nerve (n. III), trochlear nerve (n. IV) and abducens nerve (n. VI) ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranial_nerves)). **Additional nerves** innervate the ciliary muscles, which control the lens ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciliary_muscle)).

**The optic nerve (n. V)** conveys visual stimuli from the retina to the brain ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optic_nerve)). **Inflammation** of this nerve (optic neuritis) can affect vision ([Mayo Clinic](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/optic-neuritis/symptoms-causes/syc-20354953)). Other mentioned nerves are not typically affected by inflammation, but more likely by other disorders of the nerves or brain, such as [multiple sclerosis](https://www.msif.org/about-ms/symptoms-of-ms/vision-issues/) or [stroke](https://strokefoundation.org.au/About-Stroke/Help-after-stroke/Stroke-resources-and-fact-sheets/Vision-loss-after-stroke-fact-sheet). Anyway, nerve function impairment, from whatever cause, is often called **palsy,** for example, [oculomotor nerve palsy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oculomotor_nerve_palsy).

By far most common causes of impaired vision are changes in the eye bulb length (nearsightedness) and age-related rigidity of the lens (farsightedness), which are usually not associated with the nerves. Then there are various disorders of the lens (e.g. cataracts), eye chambers (e.g. glaucoma), retina and circulation (e.g. diabetes). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_impairment) has a long list of causes of visual impairment. There's a simple to read description of neurological causes of visual impairment on [Healio](https://www.healio.com/ophthalmology/neurosciences/news/print/ocular-surgery-news/%7B83ee5159-fea0-4b30-beb8-8595bbf23efe%7D/neurologic-disorders-have-varied-ocular-symptoms) and there's one study about this on [PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4173229/).

Comment: I liked your answer Jan, it won't be shown, but I did :)

Comment: OK, I wanted to say, it's a bigger picture than just nerve inflammation. Still, if you want to focus on that, you may use the term "nerve palsy" instead of inflammation when searching for more information.

Comment: I was just looking for that in facts :)

Comment: Thanks Jan, the oculomotor nerve palsy was what I was looking for.